# JSMPEG Camera stream with gstremer

Tags: javascript, ffmpeg, gstreamer, gstreamer-1.0, jsmpeg

As mentioned in the example - [Example Setup for Streaming: Raspberry Pi Live Webcam](https://github.com/phoboslab/jsmpeg#example-setup-for-streaming-raspberry-pi-live-webcam). We are able to stream webcam in browser with ffmpeg but **how can I stream with gstreamer?**.

Inshort need similar command with gstreamer...

```
ffmpeg \
    -f v4l2 \
        -framerate 25 -video_size 640x480 -i /dev/video0 \
    -f mpegts \
        -codec:v mpeg1video -s 640x480 -b:v 1000k -bf 0 \
    http://localhost:8081/supersecret
```

with gstreamer how can i send `mpeg1` codec to websoket-relay http://localhost:8081/supersecret

Able to start webcam with
`gst-launch-1.0 v4l2src device="/dev/video0" ! videoconvert ! autovideosink`

But need to send it to websocket-relay, So tried with `gst-launch-1.0 v4l2src device="/dev/video0" ! videoconvert ! tcpclientsink host=localhost port=8081` but did`t worked.. :(

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

We can be able to stream with gstreamer with below command

```
GST_DEBUG=3 gst-launch-1.0  v4l2src device=/dev/video0 ! videoconvert ! video/x-raw,framerate=30/1 ! avenc_mpeg1video ! mpegtsmux ! curlhttpsink location=http://127.0.0.1:8081/supersecret
```